# Python - Faster way to parse specific excel data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I have an excel file where each column looks like this but with like 5K rows or more:

```
ColumnName1
4|newColumn1|1.66|newCoumn2|2.6265|newCoumn3|2.2656|newCoumn4|2.9678
4|newColumn1|1.66|newCoumn2|2.6265|newCoumn3|2.2656|newCoumn4|2.9678
4|newColumn1|1.66|newCoumn2|2.6265|newCoumn3|2.2656|newCoumn4|2.9678
4|newColumn1|1.66|newCoumn2|2.6265|newCoumn3|2.2656|newCoumn4|2.9678
4|newColumn1|1.66|newCoumn2|2.6265|newCoumn3|2.2656|newCoumn4|2.9678
4|newColumn1|1.66|newCoumn2|2.6265|newCoumn3|2.2656|newCoumn4|2.9678
4|newColumn1|1.66|newCoumn2|2.6265|newCoumn3|2.2656|newCoumn4|2.9678
4|newColumn1|1.66|newCoumn2|2.6265|newCoumn3|2.2656|newCoumn4|2.9678
```

What I want to do is parse this excel file and turn it into a new excel file where - newColumn1, newColumn2, newColumn3, newColumn4 are the headers, and the data is under it like this:

```
newColumn1 newColumn2 newColumn3 newColumn4
  1.66      2.6265     2.2656      2.9678
  1.66      2.6265     2.2656      2.9678
  1.66      2.6265     2.2656      2.9678
  1.66      2.6265     2.2656      2.9678
  1.66      2.6265     2.2656      2.9678
  1.66      2.6265     2.2656      2.9678
```

My code is like this, but it's a little slow. Is there a faster way in doing it?

```
    for row in dfSpecificColumn:
        allTest = row.split("|")
        allTest.pop(0) #remove the 4| in the beginning of each line
        count = 0
        columnName = ''
        dict = OrderedDict()
        # for each test and value, insert into dictonary and for evrey line in csv add it to dataframe
        for text in allTest:
            if count % 2 == 1:
                dict[columnName] = text
            else:
                columnName = text
            count = count + 1
        dfOutputWithTestThatFailed = dfOutputWithTestThatFailed.append(dict, ignore_index=True)
    return dfOutputWithTestThatFailed
```

What I do is split by | and then add to a dictionary and then put in DF. I'm pretty sure there is faster way to run this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the "Excel" file you have an .xls, .xlsx or just a simple .csv?

Comment: it was excel but i convert it to CSV so it's faster. but my problem is in this specific area on the parse part. basically i do a lot of functions on this data, and it all happens inside a DF

Comment: What is `dfOutputWithTestThatFailed` a `pandas` `DataFrame`? Dataframes are copied on append. Its slower than just sticking with a python list.

Comment: Do you know the names of the columns in advance or are you pulling them from the data? Is it consistent? Once the names have been grabbed from the second row, can we assume they are the same throughout?

Comment: dfOutputWithTestThatFailed  is a pandas dataframe, yes.  i don't know columns names in advance but i go over the column in another function and get all the names, and only then do the function. the data is different in each cell (the numbers). the names in the second row arnt for all the column, that's why i have to go over it all. sometimes it can be in row 2300 a 9|xxx|23.23|YYY|4.23....and so on but with 9 names instead of 4 so i need to go over the column from begaining to end once

Comment: Will the column values for each row always be in the same order? Will some columns be skipped in some cases? (i.e. could you have [1,2,3] [2,1,3] as well as [1,3] and [1,2,3,4]?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the series `ColumnName1` around the delimiter `|` which produces a series of list of elements, then you can use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to apply a custom function which transforms each list of elements in the series to the `pd.Series` in the desired format:

```
result = (
    df['ColumnName1'].str.split('|')
    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[2::2], index=x[1::2]))
)
```

Output:

```
# print(result)

  newColumn1 newColumn2 newColumn3 newColumn4
0       1.66     2.6265     2.2656     2.9678
1       1.66     2.6265     2.2656     2.9678
2       1.66     2.6265     2.2656     2.9678
3       1.66     2.6265     2.2656     2.9678
4       1.66     2.6265     2.2656     2.9678
5       1.66     2.6265     2.2656     2.9678
6       1.66     2.6265     2.2656     2.9678
7       1.66     2.6265     2.2656     2.9678
```

---

Edit (refer comments):
Without using lambda function:

```
def fx(x):
    # Example of x = [4, newColumn1, 1.66, newColumn2, 2.6265, newColumn3, 2.2656, newColumn4, 2.9678]
    return pd.Series(x[2::2], index=x[1::2]) # Instantiate a pandas series from the list `x` and returns it.

result = df['ColumnName1'].str.split('|').apply(fx)
```

Comment: i used this, instead of 75 seconds for a column it took 11! thanks a lot. i wanted to know what exactly is the lambda expression doing if you can explain? or if maybe if you write how to do it not with lambda but with loops i will understand alone. thanks again!

Comment: The `df['ColumnName1'].apply` is iterating over the column line by line, so for a given line in column the lambda function is just transforming the given line into pandas series. *Note: each line in the column is the list of tokens like `[4, newColumn1, 1.66, newCoumn2, 2.6265, newCoumn3, 2.2656, newCoumn4, 2.9678]` which are obtained from using `str.split`*

Comment: @Itzik If this answered your question you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.

Comment: thanks yes, i just don't understand the (x[2::2], index=x[1::2]) part, how does it skip the first value ? and also i have a problem that when the box is none it crashes so i'm trying to add an "if" statement and having some trouble.
like if i have a row like this:    | ----------------  = /n |      
ColumnName1 ---------------- 
4|newColumn1|1.66|newCoumn2|2.6265|newCoumn3|2.2656|newCoumn4|2.9678 ------------------ 
None ---------------- 4|newColumn1|1.66|newCoumn2|2.6265|newCoumn3|2.2656|newCoumn4|2.9678 ----------------

Comment: `x[2::2]` is just a slicing notation for list which returns `[1.66, 2.6265, 2.2656, 2.9678]` . Similarly, `x[1::2]` returns the headers `[newColumn1, newColumn2, newColumn3, newColumn4]` –

Comment: What is box? Can you properly paste the row which is creating problem in your question?

Comment: it's hard because i can't format nicely here in commnet but if my original column is like this:
Column 1 __________
4|newColumn1|1.66|newCoumn2|2.6265|newCoumn3|2.2656|newCoumn4|2.9678  __________
this is an empty row  __________
4|newColumn1|1.66|newCoumn2|2.6265|newCoumn3|2.2656|newCoumn4|2.9678 _____ then i get an error "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" because the row was empty and it can't do the lambda expression

Comment: What return value for the empty row do you expect in such case?

Comment: just make the cell stay empty, as it was before

Comment: It's really hard to guess whats your row contains, can you include a part sample of the dataframe where the row is empty? Just use `print(df)` and include the output in your question.

Comment: If line 4 and 7 did not exists, it works perfectly, but if i have those spaces. it crashes. this is the input and the output i want
https://i.imgur.com/MAFJHRB.jpg

Comment: Why don't you skip those empty rows while reading the dataframe?

Comment: i guess ill just use ".dropna()" thanks for the help and all the comments

Comment: Yep, you can always drop the empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

As you indicated the data is in .csv format, something as simple as this works:

```
with open('myinput.csv', 'r') as f:
    # skip the header
    next(f)
    first_row = next(f).split('|')
    # not assuming 4 columns, reading from the first line
    n = first_row(int(n))
    with open('myoutput.csv', 'w') as f_out:
        # write output header
        f_out.write(first_row[1::2])
        # write first line of data
        f_out.write(first_row[2::2])
        # loop over the rest of the lines, split and only take the data
        for line in f_in:
            f_out.write(line.split('|')[2::2])
```